# How to have custom ProblemDetails in .net core

Tags: asp.net-core

I am looking to return my own ProblemDetail object.

I currently have a middleware for exceptions that catches 500 errors. I'm looking to possibly create another middleware to capture api errors.

I've seen many results on google about utilizing ProblemDetail (`.AddProblemDetail`) but nothing about creating one. but I would like to create my own and return my own object.

Comment: On the contrary, this is very well documented in the official docs. Have you checked [Handle errors in ASP.NET Core web APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-7.0) ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  There's many search results about utilizing problem details, even extending and customizing. But not one about Creating and return your own problem detail. That document unfortunately doesn't answer my question =(

Comment: What *is* the question? That document does show how you can customize the response for the entire application  and even how to return your own problem response in an action with `return Problem(...)`. You can create your own `ProblemDetails` instance and just return it, or wrap in in an `ObjectResult` with your desired status code.

Comment: You may be asking how to use a completely different class in your actions - something you can already do. Or how to return your own JSON result even in 500 errors - that's also shown, using `UseExceptionHandler`

Answer (score 2):

You can add your custom object to ProblemDetails. According to [Handle Errors > Implement ProblemDetailsFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-7.0#implement-problemdetailsfactory), you can implement the `ProblemDetailsFactory` abstract class. Within the class, 2 methods `CreateProblemDetails` and `CreateProblemDetails` should be implemented. You could add your own object in the "extensions" property like below.

```cs
public class SampleProblemDetailsFactory : ProblemDetailsFactory
{
    public override ProblemDetails CreateProblemDetails(HttpContext httpContext, int? statusCode = null, string? title = null, string? type = null, string? detail = null, string? instance = null)
    {
        var problemDetails = new ProblemDetails
        {
            Status = statusCode, //You could delete these original property and only leave the Extensions property.
            Title = title,
            Type = type,
            Detail = detail,
            Instance = instance,
            Extensions =
                    {
                        { "extend1", "info1" },
                        { "extend2", "info2" }
                    }
        };
        return problemDetails;
        
    }

    public override ValidationProblemDetails CreateValidationProblemDetails(HttpContext httpContext, ModelStateDictionary modelStateDictionary, int? statusCode = null, string? title = null, string? type = null, string? detail = null, string? instance = null)
    {
        var validationproblemdetails = new ValidationProblemDetails
        {
            Status = statusCode,
        };
        return validationproblemdetails;
    }
}
```

**Program.cs**

```cs
builder.Services.AddTransient<ProblemDetailsFactory, SampleProblemDetailsFactory>();
builder.Services.AddProblemDetails();
```

### Examples

[image]

Or only leave the extension property (won't be able to delete the "exception")

[image]

Comment: The link points back to this question. Did you mean to link to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-7.0) perhaps?

Comment: Yes, sorry I modified.

Comment: Sorry not quite what I am looking for. I want to create me own object instead of extending the current one. Thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

You can look into [this](https://github.com/ProhelikaX/Prohelika.Template.CleanArchitecture/blob/main/src/Presentation/Prohelika.Template.CleanArchitecture.Presentation.WebAPI/Extensions/ProblemDetailsExtension.cs) and the repo. Basically it involves throwing custom exceptions, creating a *ProblemDetailsToJsonExtension* and creating and using middleware to catch that exception and returning it as a **ProblemDetails** JSON.

Comment: Unfortunately, the link is dead and the answer is not of much value without it.

Comment: Link updated. Please check!

Comment: Awesome - can you also please inline any critical info from the link to make sure it persists in this post regardless of external resources.  That would be amazing!

Comment: I will update the answer when I have time.